# litorrent python binding: Library not loaded: libboost_python38.dylib

Tags: python, c++, boost, libtorrent

#### Use case

I am trying to develop a torrent client of my own, I found that `libtorrent` is one of the efficient ways of achieving this. But while going through its documentation for the setup I came across multiple things I am not able to interlink. So there are two questions to this.

#### Question

I want to follow [this](https://www.libtorrent.org/python_binding.html) doc and achieve it through that only instead of installing it through `python-libtorrent`

As per the doc, for the pre-requisites as per [libtorrent pre requisites](https://www.libtorrent.org/building.html), one must have boost setup and b2 set up on their system. Following are the commands that I executed:-

1. Downloaded: boost_1_76_0.tar.bz2  from https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.76.0/source/
2. Untar the file and went inside and ran `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/lib/bootstrap`
3. `./b2 install --prefix=/usr/lib/b2`
4. Added `/usr/lib/b2/bin` in the PATH environment variable  ->

   `export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:/usr/lib/b2/bin:$PATH"`
5. Setting BOOST_BUILD_PATH && BOOST_ROOT ->

   ```
   export BOOST_ROOT=/Users/pratapalokraj/boost_1_76_0
   export BOOST_BUILD_PATH=$BOOST_ROOT/tools/build
   ```
6. I don't understand why in this doc (https://www.libtorrent.org/building.html) it's asking to run the `cmake` command ( I think it's not related to my stuff, so I skipped it).
7. Got inside `libtorrent` folder and ran the below commands: -

   ```
   python setup.py build
   python setup.py install
   ```

8 Now when I am trying to import `libtorrent`, it's throwing an error:-

```
(base) Apples-MacBook-Pro:libtorrent cobyUser$ python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 11:26:31)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libtorrent as lt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/python_libtorrent-2.0.4-py3.8-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/libtorrent.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libboost_python38.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/python_libtorrent-2.0.4-py3.8-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/libtorrent.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

The above question is related to the setup issue I am facing.

### Update/solution

After searching a lot, I found few docs here: [quickbook-install](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/quickbook/install.html) and I don't know exactly what happened but I did execute the below steps and now python is able to recognize the libtorrent library.

1. `vi ~/user-config.jam`

   pasted the below content

   ```
   using xsltproc
        : /opt/local/bin/xsltproc
        ;

    using boostbook
        : /opt/local/share/xsl/docbook-xsl/
        : /opt/local/share/xml/docbook/4.2
        ;
   ```
2. `sudo port install libxslt docbook-xsl-nons docbook-xml-4.2`
3. Went inside the libtorrent folder, and ran `b2 variant=release link=static runtime-link=static debug-symbols=on`
4. `b2 install --prefix=/usr/local`

I think maybe a few dependencies were missing. But I still have doubt about what and how this Python binding is working. I didn't understand the exact concept of boost libraries and b2.

If someone can point in the correct direction and give a brief overview I would really appreciate it, especially what `b2 variant=release link=static runtime-link=static debug-symbols=on` is doing. What do we exactly mean when we say static linking of libraries.

Note: for people like me who are struggling to build libtorrent from source, `b2` is an updated name of `bjam`. You can find the reference [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/bbv2/faq.html#:%7E:text=Build%20engine%20is%20derived%20from,executable%20was%20changed%20to%20b2%20.).

Comment: I think you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. libtorrent can link against installed boost libraries (default) or against a boost source installation (if `BOOST_ROOT` is set). You seem to be trying to do both; building and installing boost *and* setting `BOOST_ROOT`. Question 1 doesn't really have a question. You get an error message suggesting that one boost library (and probably other ones too) are not installed. You probably need to install boost in the anaconda environment.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for in question 2.

Comment: Hi @Arvid, thanks for replying. I have the BOOST_ROOT set but what do you exactly mean by installing it in anaconda environment?

Comment: I am completely new to C++ boost library and python bindings, I did follow the libtorrent docs, endded up with errror, and also I am not able to exactly understand why am I doing those steps. Like what exactly is b2 building in the project, and when we are building does it means it making that litorrent library globally available and if so then how to set it up for a virtual environment

Comment: And one more thing what exactly does it mean when you are saying "installed boost libraries (default) or against a boost source installation". I never had a c++ setup on my macbook, I just executed the above steps mentioned in the question

Comment: @Arvid, I was venturing through one of your answers and it states that doing `sudo apt-get install python-libtorrent` will resolve the problem. Can you help me with why my method that I followed using libtorrent docs didn't work. Or is there any way I can see somewhere what exactly the above sudo command is internally running

Comment: I mistakenly thought you were running it in a *conda* environment, so please disregard that statement. Fundamentally, when building software that is split up into different shared libraries (.so, .dll), the operating system loader needs to know where to find those libraries at run-time. They need to be installed in a path that operating system expects (and sometimes in the same directory as the executable is one of those). As far as I can tell, the boost python library cannot be found for you. An alternative is to link statically against libraries, that also has challenges (with `-fPIC`)

Comment: I don't understand why you want to install xslt. I would suggest that if you need help building libtorrent, either ask on the mailing list or the github discussions. You need to include both the commands you're running and the errors they fail with

Comment: it also looks like you may have misunderstood what `--prefix=` means. That's essentially the directory to install into

Comment: No, No I understand what `--prefix`, that is not the problem. I miss understanding of the static and dynamic linking of libraries. Can you please give me a brief understanding of what `b2 variant=release link=static runtime-link=static debug-symbols=on` is doing?

Comment: on stack overflow you're supposed to ask questions as questions, not as comments. It's not practical to have dialogs here.

Comment: Yeah I also think so, I have updated the question accordingly. If you can help it would be really great

Comment: you don't need to install quickbook to build and install libtorrent

Comment: "question 2" is still not a question. Just a series of statements. It's hard to know what you're looking for

Comment: Let me rephrase the question for you here: -
1) What exactly is static and dynamic linking of libraries?
2) What is b2 and how is it binding libtorrent to c++ boost libraries and how python interpreter is able to identify the boost libraries and integrate it?

Comment: Sorry if `Question 2` seems to be a bit messy to understand for you. I will rephrase that in sometime